# prettify json string vuejs2 webpack

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, vuejs2

i try filter my json string into JSON highlight syntax or kinda like a json prettify with pre element tags. I dont want a tree json viewer but just a nice JSON syntax highlight.

template

```
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{{ json | jsonPretty }}}</pre>
</div>
```

vue

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      json:'{ "name: "John Doe" }'
    }
  },
  filters: {
    jsonPretty: function(value) {
      let json = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(value), null, 2)
      json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
      return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+]?\d+)?)/g, function(match) {
        var cls = 'number'
        if (/^"/.test(match)) {
          if (/:$/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'key'
          } else {
            cls = 'string'
          }
        } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
          cls = 'boolean'
        } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
          cls = 'null'
        }
        return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>'
      })
    }
  }
});
```

CSS

```
pre {
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px; 
  margin: 5px;
  background: white;
 }
.string { color: green; }
.number { color: darkorange; }
.boolean { color: blue; }
.null { color: magenta; }
.key { color: red; }
```

i try at jsfiddle, it's working but when i try with webpack official vuejs template, it show error

```
ERROR in ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-4b8ecaca","hasScoped":true,"transformToRequire":{"video":"src","source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"}}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/Hello.vue
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 
  Error compiling template:

  <div class="hello">
    <div class="">

      <pre>{{{ json | jsonPretty }}}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>

  - invalid expression: {{{ json | jsonPretty }}}

 @ ./src/components/Hello.vue 10:2-300
 @ ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

EDIT : add jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljck1wmL/5/

Comment: A Vue instance's `data` should **not** be a function. Only components have that requirement

Comment: @Phil it has html tag. i wrap some match regex string with spesific class span tag. So i can style it.

Comment: You're using Vue v1 in your JSFiddle. Which version of Vue and vue-loader are you using locally?

Comment: @Phil i user vue 2 and vue-loader ^12. i try change my filter with computed data.  it parse span tag with spesific class. but it not render style. it has something todo with vuejs live cycle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind can't find any documentation for that `{{{ html }}}` syntax. According to the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html?#Raw-HTML), you should use the `v-html` directive.

Also, Vue 2.x filters are only available within moustache and `v-bind` expressions. [You cannot use a filter in `v-html`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4352).

For anything else, you should use a computed property or method.

```
<pre v-html="prettyAreaData"></pre>
```

and

```
computed: {
  prettyAreaData: function() {
    var value = this.areaData;
    // and so on with the rest of your function
```

I've updated your JSFiddle to use Vue 2.x which I assume you're using locally. I've also fixed that `data` function to be a plain object.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljck1wmL/7/

Comment: i've tried with computed data and function too, but css not rendered.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"css not rendered"*. Do you mean the styles in your CSS are not being applied? If so, how is your CSS included? If it's in a stand-alone component (eg `Hello.vue`), it should be in a `<style>` tag

Comment: yeah i mean css are not being applied. i put all css in style scoped tag

Comment: @IbnuHabibie you should use your browser's developer tools to inspect the elements and find out why the CSS isn't being applied.

Comment: i've changed filter to method and put css style at global. Now problem is solved. thank you.